# php "hello word" error message when run on GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, installation

I followed the instructions on [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/installingmac) for installing the SDK and running "Hello, World!". The following error is shown on my localhost:8080

> Notice: Use of undefined constant GAE_INCLUDE_REQUIRE_GS_STREAMS - assumed 'GAE_INCLUDE_REQUIRE_GS_STREAMS' in /Users/mhmhsh/google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Setup.php on line 32
>   Hello, World!

I haven't found any thing related to this error on google. It seems that the constant 'GAE_INCLUDE_REQUIRE_GS_STREAMS' is not defined anywhere else in the package. Why haven't others reported the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there was a glitch in the just-released 1.8.1 SDK for PHP, and that the fix is to edit /google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php, adding the following to the $setup function definition:

```
  $allowed_buckets = ini_get(
      'google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets');
  define('GAE_INCLUDE_REQUIRE_GS_STREAMS',
         // All values are considered true except the empty string.
         $allowed_buckets ? 1 : 0);
```

(I'll confirm and update this message).
I expect that a new version of the SDK will be uploaded very soon that fixes that issue.

Update: yes, this is the correct patch.  The SDK for the next release, which fixes this, should be available within a few weeks.

Comment: Your fix has worked with me, but I will wait for the update. Thanks!